# bending 1/4" natural gas tubing

Tags: natural-gas

I'm going to install a new tube for my pilot light gas supply. Should I consider using a tubing bender, or is that just silly? I can bend it easily by hand, but I don't want to risk kinks.

I can get a bender for under $15, but I don't know if these are meant for such soft tube like these pilot supply tubes.

For reference, I'm using this kind of tube:
[image: 1/4" aluminum tube]
I'm considering one of these benders:
[image: tekton tubing bender]
or
[image: small tubing bender]

Answer (score 3):

A tubing bender works quite well on this stuff and isn't expensive. An alternative you may want to consider for more open bends is an external bending spring if you can get one in the right size.

Bending by hand is quite likely to kink the tube and isn't a good idea.

What is the tube made of? It doesn't look like copper in the picture. Aluminium won't bend nicely or at all, steel needs a tool even more than copper.

When using a pipe bender on thin stuff, take it easy and release the tool a few times rather than trying to make the whole bend in one movement.

Comment: The tube is aluminum and rather pliable. It is fairly easy to bend by hand.